# Having trouble with the user programers guide

Tags: python, linux, fiware, fiware-orion

I am doing the excercise on [this site](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide). I have followed the  example exactly and without any problem until I got to Context subscriptions:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "temperature"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL",
            "condValues": [
                "PT10S"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

When I type that code, I get the expected answer:

```
{
    "subscribeResponse": {
        "duration": "P1M",
        "subscriptionId": "51c04a21d714fb3b37d7d5a7"
    }
}
```

But then this sentence confuses me:

> If you look at the accumulator-script.py terminal window, you will see
>   that a message resembling the following one is received each 10
>   seconds:

What I do here is enter this command: `python accumulator-server.py`
But the output (updated every 10 seconds) I get is: `127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2015 10:52:56] "POST /accumulate HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Am I missing something here since Im not getting the expected output simmilar like the one mentioned in the tutorial?

```
POST http://localhost:1028/accumulate
Content-Length: 492
User-Agent: orion/0.9.0
Host: localhost:1028
Accept: application/xml, application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "subscriptionId" : "51c04a21d714fb3b37d7d5a7",
  "originator" : "localhost",
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "temperature",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "26.5"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "Room",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "Room1"
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I not running the python script correctly or? Btw I'm new to both python and linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Starting_accumulator_server_for_the_tutorials), the way of running accumulator is the following one:

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate ::1 on
```

Comment: Yeah, I just came here to post this and say that I figured it out. Thanks...
I just have a follow up question: suppose the script was on another computer and I was accessing it through ssh? Would i just change the local-host to the machine name here `(curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContextSubscription -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool)`

Comment: if the script runs in a diferent host than Orion, then you have to set the `reference` field in the subscription properly, i.e. instead of using "http://localhost:1028/accumulate", use the right IP/name instead of "localhost".

Comment: One more question: In a real enterprise application for example, the provided script would not be enough? Im not really sure what this script does, except that it answers? does it even store room1 and 2 data in my mongoDB? and is it advisable to configure the script using cygnus to store the subscribed data in mySQL DB for example?

Comment: The accumulstor-server.py script is designed to be used for learning and debugging. It only prints notification messages as they are received "on the wire" in the stadard output, it doesn't store notification information in DB or interact with any other external system, that can be achieved using Cygnus. If you have more questions (specially the ones related with Cygnus) I'd suggest to post them as separte StackOverflow questions. Thanks!